# Crystal no overload matches 'Array(Type)#[]' with type (Int32 | Nil)

Tags: crystal-lang

I am finding some weird behavior when using index.

```
#Defined in the class's initialize    
@my_list = [] of Type

index = @my_list.index { |i| i.value == 2 } # => 0

@my_list[0] # => 2
@my_list[index] # => error
```

I get the error:

> no overload matches 'Array(Type)#[]' with type (Int32 | Nil)

Not sure why index does not work, as index = 0.

EDIT:

More information. If I do this:

```
if index == nil
  #Do something
#error => undefined method '>=' for Nil (compile-time type is (Int32 | Nil))
elsif index >= 0
  #Do something else
end
```

Which I understand. It could be nil, but since I'm already checking to see if it is nil there shouldn't be a problem here. I'm thinking the previous code snippet is running into the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Array#index is nilable; it may not find anything and return nil, hence it returns an Int32|Nil union.

The compiler eventually fails because Array#[] expects an Int32 argument, but we pass it an Int32|Nil. You must take care of this case (to avoid later bugs) by checking if the return value is truthy for example.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @julien-portalier :

> The problem is that Array#index is nilable; it may not find anything in the array and return Nil, hence it returns an (Int32 | Nil) union.

You can use [Object#not_nil!](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.18.7/Object.html#not_nil%21-instance-method) to get ride of the Nil type :

```
@my_list = [2, 4, 6, 8]

index = @my_list.index { |i| i == 6 }.not_nil! # => 2
# compile type of 'index' is Int32

@my_list[0] # => 2
@my_list[index] # => 6
```

It will make sure the type returned by `Array#index` is not `Nil`, if it is, an exception will be raised (see [Nil#not_nil!](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.18.7/Nil.html#not_nil%21-instance-method))

---

And if you need to handle an index error without using exceptions, you can simply check if `Array#index` failed :

```
@my_list = [2, 4, 6, 8]

index = @my_list.index { |i| i == 6 } # => 2
# compile-time type of 'index' is (Int32 | Nil)

if index
    # In this scope, compile-time type of 'index' is Int32
    @my_list[0] # => 2
    @my_list[index] # => 6
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to do this:

```
def get_index(val)
  i = 0
  while i < @my_list.size
    if @my_list[i].value == val
       return i
    end

    i += 1
  end

  return -1
end
```

This way only int values will be returned, no nils. It seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

better way is to use `times` method it's more simple and more clear:

```
def get_index(val)
  @my_list.size.times do |i|
    return i if @my_list[i] == val
  end
  -1
end
```

**UPD**

or more simple

```
def get_index(val)
  @my_list.index { |value| value == val } || -1
end
```